# community-awarded bounty?

Tags: discussion

In [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/227146/hosting-online-with-xampp/229760#229760) if you hover over the bounty (+50) it says "This answer has been awarded  bounty of 50 Reputation by Community" Have I missed something where the community "bot" can mark an answer and award the bounty?

Comment: There's a lot more here: http://superuser.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties&sort=offered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, community can award the bounty under certain conditions, see

https://superuser.com/faq#bounty

Comment: thanks. Reading through the FaQ, was the reason the account was suspended for using a signature/tagline?

Comment: @tombull89 Suspensions are considered private and only discussed with the person in suspension, unless they make it public on meta.

Comment: @Diago, ah ok. It's just such a rare occurance (as I see it anyway) I'd thought I'd ask.

Comment: @tombull89 It happens more often then you think :)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.